# Android - "below" tag doesn' work

Tags: android

I want to make a top-centered frame, with one caption on top-center and the other one below the first caption, on the left side of the frame. But my code doesn't work properly:

```
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainWrapper);
    RelativeLayout frame = new RelativeLayout(this);

    //ustawiamy parametry ramki
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frameParams.width = (int)(0.8 * screenWidth);
    frameParams.height = 250;
    frameParams.setMargins(0,50,0,0);
    frameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    frame.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

    //utworzenie napisów
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textRL1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT),
                                textRL2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView routeName = new TextView(this);
    routeName.setText(name);
    routeName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 14);
    textRL1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    textRL1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    TextView routeSource = new TextView(this);
    routeSource.setText("z: " + source);
    routeSource.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 9);
    textRL2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, routeName.getId());


    //dodanie elementów do ramki
    frame.addView(routeName, textRL1);     
    frame.addView(routeSource, textRL2);
    linearLayout.addView(frame);   
    setContentView(linearLayout);
```

The effect of this code is this (caption2 is not below the first one).
[enter link description here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/29wv6zs.jpg)

Comment: That worked. I thought, that every created element has its own id assigned automatically. Looks like that's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `routeName` view doesn't have an id `!= 0` unless you give it one. Layout rules with a zero id won't work, the zero is treated as "nothing".

Add e.g. `routeName.setId(1)` to give the view a non-zero id that you can use later with relative layout rules.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set an `id` to `routeName`

You need to do

```
routeName.setId(someId);
```

where `someId` is an `int` that is not 0.

Comment: More specifically, an `int` that is not 0.